# Registering Django system checks in AppConfig's ready() method

Tags: django

In the docs for Django's [System check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/checks/#registering-and-labeling-checks) it says:

> Checks should be registered in a file that’s loaded when your application is loaded; for example, in the [`AppConfig.ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.

None of the examples on that page, or around the `AppConfig.ready()` method, show how to do this. Given a checking method like:

```
from django.core.checks import register, Tags

@register(Tags.compatibility)
def my_check(app_configs, **kwargs):
    # ... perform compatibility checks and collect errors
    return errors
```

How would you do this in/from the `AppConfig.ready()` method? Is one called from the other? Which file should the above method go in? Do you add `@register(...)` to the `ready()` method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From reading [the examples on this page](http://andrewsforge.com/article/upgrading-django-to-17/part-3-django-17-new-features/) about the Apps Registry and System Checks Framework, it seems there are (at least) two ways to add your own System Checks. To adapt that page's examples (assuming you're creating an app called `myapp`):

---

1) Create a `myapp/checks.py` file like this:

```
from django.apps import apps as camelot_apps
from django.core.checks import register, Warning
from django.core.checks import Tags as DjangoTags

class Tags(DjangoTags):
    """Do this if none of the existing tags work for you:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/checks/#builtin-tags
    """
    my_new_tag = 'my_new_tag'

@register(Tags.my_new_tag)
def check_taggit_is_installed(app_configs=None, **kwargs):
    "Check that django-taggit is installed when usying myapp."
    errors = []
    try:
        from taggit import models
    except ImportError:
        errors.append(
            Warning(
                "The django-taggit app is required to use myapp.",
                hint=("Install django-taggit"),
                # A unique ID so it's easier to find this warning:
                id='myapp.W001',
            )
        )
    return errors
```

And then in `myapp/__init__.py` (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
from . import checks
```

Running this should run that check above:

```
$ ./manage.py check myapp
```

---

2) Or, as I thought in my initial question, you can register that check in your AppConfig. So, keep the above code in `myapp/check.py`, but remove the `@register(Tags.my_new_tag)` line.

Then create `myapp/apps.py` containing this:

```
from django.core.checks import register
from .checks import Tags, check_taggit_is_installed

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        super(MyappConfig, self).ready()
        register(Tags.my_new_tag)(check_taggit_is_installed)
```

And alter `myapps/__init__.py` so it contains this:

```
from . import checks
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
```

---

The first example seems simpler, with no need for a custom AppConfig.

Comment: Nice one, you are close with this answer but slightly more complicated than necessary. Anyway, you had my upvotes in the past.

Comment: [From Django 1.9 docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)
"New applications should avoid `default_app_config`. Instead they should require the dotted path to the appropriate `AppConfig` subclass to be configured explicitly in `INSTALLED_APPS`."


Instead of `default_app_config` you can specify full path to new config-class in your  `INSTALLED_APPS`, e.g.:
    INSTALLED_APPS = [...
        'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
   ... ]

Answer (score 13):

[Django recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/checks/#registering-and-labeling-checks):

> Checks should be registered in a file that’s loaded when your application is loaded; for example, in the `AppConfig.ready()` method.

Therefore, place the checks code in a `checks.py` file. Then simply in `apps.py`, as with signals:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'MyApp'
    verbose_name = "My App"

    def ready(self):
        # import myapp.signals
        import myapp.checks
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So I would still have the code in `myapp/checks.py`, as in option (1) of my answer? And then instead of putting `from . import checks` in `myapp/__init__.py` I would do as you outline here?

Comment: Welcome. Well, yes. For a working example take a look at https://github.com/Wtower/django-ninecms/blob/devel/ninecms/checks.py and https://github.com/Wtower/django-ninecms/blob/devel/ninecms/apps.py

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can just place this code in `ready()` method. For example of usage you can take a look at `django.contrib.auth` (or other `contrib` app). This app has check in `checks.py` file, that imported in `apps.py` and registered in `ready()` method: [checks.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/checks.py), [apps.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/apps.py).